# Ubuntu terminal not displaying all values

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have a C program that displays all the possibilities of the letters "A-B-C-D-E-F" can make. That comes to 720 possibilities. But my terminal is only displaying 511 possibilities. I tried looking online on how to edit terminal settings and found this following and did them. I went into edit>profile preferences and selected "use custom terminal size" and set both the values for rows and columns to 800. Sadly only 511 continues to display.

Can someone please tell me what is the solution to this, im really puzzled.

PS: Every entry is on its own line. For example:

```
ABCDEF
ABDCEF
......
......
```

Comment: Could you paste a sample of the output so we can see what it looks like?  Is every entry on its own line?

Comment: Yes, every entry is in its own line.

Comment: Please provide some sample code. Also, try flushing the console buffer.

Comment: Redirecting the output to a file would seem like a far more sensible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the **Scrolling** tab and set the number of lines in scroll buffer to something higher than 512.

Another useful utility to know about is `less`.  You can pipe the output of your program into it and it lets you scroll around and search through the output:

```
my_program | less
```

Comment: Do you know where i can find this? Cause in my Ubuntu terminal I went into edit>profile preferences and selected "use custom terminal size" and set both the values for rows and columns to 800. But nothing changed

Comment: Do you see the Scrolling tab?  If not, what tabs do you see?  On my computer, it looks something like this image  that I just found:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/GRZWD.png

Comment: Thank you soo much! I found it and it worked. What does use custom terminal size mean? It was what i edited before? Once again thank you so much.

Comment: Those settings affect the behavior of advanced applications the like `pico` that know the height and width of your terminal.  You should probably change those settings back.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `less` described by [David Grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26070948/1440565), you should also be familiar with redirection:

```
my_program > outputfile.out
```

This creates a new file (or overwrites an existing one) with the output from your program. Now you can open the file in a text editor to look at the output. You can also use the `wc` utility to count the number of lines:

```
wc outputfile.out
```

If you only want to check that your program creates the correct amount of output, you can use the following pipe:

```
my_program | wc
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Of course, the output itself might be useful for other things than just the word count.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to see all the output answers.you can see the answer from "answer" after you execute the program like  a.out>answer.
now open the file(answer),you will see the result.
">" is a operator